# Most efficient way to create a HashMap from Vector fields

Tags: rust

Let's say we have a vector of structs:

```
struct Item {
    id: u32,
    name: String,
    // ...
}

let mut items: Vec<Item> = vec!(
    Item { id: 54, name: "Foo".into() },
    Item { id: 87, name: "Bar".into() });
```

What is the most efficient way to create a HashMap that looks like this:

```
{87: "Bar", 54: "Foo"}
```

?

By "efficient", in this case I mostly mean "less verbose". Why? Because I feel in *most* real-world cases a slight performance penalty wouldn't really matter. But when it *does* matter, one can always resort to `HashMap::with_capacity()` and a simple loop, for example. Nonetheless, all else equal, I would of course prefer a solution that is faster and uses less memory.

The simplest thing I could come up with was:

```
let temp_tuples = items.iter().map(|x| (x.id, x.name.clone())).collect::<Vec<_>>();
let map_names_by_id: HashMap<_, _> = temp_tuples.into_iter().collect();
```

That surely isn't the most performant solution, as it creates a temporary vector of tuples, but as I said, I mostly care about convenience & brevity in this case. So, is there something simpler than that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need to collect to a `Vec` in between:

```
let map_names_by_id: HashMap<_, _> =
    items.iter().map(|x| (x.id, x.name.clone())).collect();
```

Comment: Now that I see your solution, it looks so obvious that `collect()` can simply use the result of `map()`! Thanks! :)